# What kind of SSD is compatible with MacBook Unibody white mid 2010?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, ssd, upgrade

This question is inspired to: [What kind of SSD is compatible with the 2010 Unibody MacBook?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45927/what-kind-of-ssd-is-compatible-with-the-2010-unibody-macbook)

I am reading here, [MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP583?viewlocale=en_US&locale=it_IT)  that the suggested SSD are 128GB, 256GB, or 512GB solid-state drive.

Is there any problem if I buy a 240 GB which seems to be easier to find? Someone in the first link even says we can buy up to 2TB. I'm asking because I am having problems in finding 256GB, so I'm worried about compatibility with 240GB.